# Using FFMPEG and LibAV

Tags: ffmpeg, multimedia, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I am trying to implement a software that can read from multiple video and audio sources. The software pipeline works like this: Read from devices -> perform some computations -> write the data. I initially thought of using ffmpeg libraries. At first I want to use libavdevice to read from all of the available devices. However I found it difficult to find proper documentation for the libav*** libraries in ffmpeg package. My questions:

1. Is there a better suggestion than libav***? In future I also want to create video files from the captured data.
2. Is there a suitable documentation for libav*** libraries? I haven't seen any on libavdevice over the google.
3. Is there a way to have polling rather than waiting for frames to be captured? example: a lot of time and threads will be wasted just to read from camera @ 15 FPS. Probably there is a way to poll the camera or mic?

Thanks you all.

Comment: Depending on your application, it may actually be preferable to simply use FFmpeg directly.  It can use STDIO, and can read from capture devices out of the box.

Comment: I don't think so, in fact the computation is realtime. Meaning that the frames that are captured will be processed right after, not something like record as whole and then process as whole. I would love it if ffmpeg had something to give frames in realtime.

Comment: You want raw frames, frame by frame?

Comment: Exactly. And I prefer to poll the webcam and not waste a thread on reading it (whenever there is a frame we go grab it, not wait till the frame is ready and then grab it). Something like select with file descriptors if it is possible.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are thinking is wasted by having a thread to handle capture.

Comment: I think that if a thread is just waiting on the camera, it is still in the queue of waiting threads. When it takes the CPU, it just wastes the time and does nothing but wait. My application will at some point probably work with a dozen of cameras and that is not all of it. It also performs face detection, facial landamrk detection, etc. I think most of the application time is just going to be waiting on the cameras!

Comment: But, why cripple the architecture of your application?  Just have the thread sleep while it waits.

Comment: I agree that having a thread sleep while it waits helps. But I don't think ffmpeg implements it like that. Also, I feel like to be able to implement the sleep approach, you need to wait for the camera for small amount of time and if the frame wasn't ready on that time you sleep, if not you read from it. It is also partially polling. Let me know if I got your idea right. Thank you for your passion about my question.

Comment: I think you should start by reading the stream of data.  I think you will find it to be more flowing than chunk by chunk with a frame in each.  Once your application is working, you can optimize the core of capturing and processing.  In any case, what you are doing has a ton of overhead.  A lot of it has also been done before.  Have you considered using a computer vision framework that already exists, like OpenCV?  This is getting out of the realm of my experience, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually my major is in computer vision and I would love to use OpenCV for this. Unfortunately there is a lot of other devices also in the mix, such as motion capture devices, kinect, audio, etc and maybe multiple of each. I have resolved the issue for the video and I am happy to share it if there ever is  a need for it. I am taking other devices in the polling mix one at a time. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: You should post your solution, or at least a synopsis of it, as an answer to your question.